# Emulating ActionBar Divider

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom toolbar with icons, etc that is modeled after the Android 3.x `ActionBar`.

One thing I'd like to add are dividers modeled after the `ActionBar` dividers.

I grabbed the 9-patch divider image from the SDK, and then tried incorporating that in a drawable that I set as the image for a 1dp wide `ImageView`, but no luck. Here is the Drawable XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nine-patch xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/divider_vertical_holo_dark"
    android:dither="true" />
```

Here is the 'divider' `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_notification_div"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toolbar_notification_txt_accel"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_actionbar_div"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc_div" />
```

Te end result is that nothing shows up for the divider. Any pointers?

EDIT:

Note that I am turning the various Image and TextViews to `View.VISIBLE` in the application itself depending on state. Assume they are all visible.

Comment: Are you trying to do this on pre-honeycomb devices? Stupid question... have you considered acionbarsherlock?

Comment: Nope, post 3.x. Have a secondary toolbar that is floated to the bottom of a drawing app, just trying to emulate ActionBar look and feel in a very simple way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem, I was using `android:src`, when I should have been using `android:background`:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_notification_div"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toolbar_notification_txt_accel"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_actionbar_div"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc_div" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ImageView` has `android:visibility="gone"`, so it won't be shown.

Comment: I only show the various Image and TextViews based on application state, but assume that I am turning all of them to VISIBLE.